# Is there a way to check how much of a file is present in the disk page cache?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to see how many blocks of a file are being stored in the kernel's disk page cache. Is there any interface I can look into to check this out? Perhaps something in `/proc`?

Comment: If nothing else, `mmap` followed by `mincore` could be abused to that effect. If `mincore` tells you a page within the mapping is in core, then it's factually in the page cache (and, also, in your process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing like that in `/proc`. The overhead of tracking that information and exposing it via `/proc` would likely be prohibitive.

As Damon suggested your best bet is `mmap()`'ing the file and using `mincore()`.

**Update**: I coded up the `mincore()` idea and it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fincore](http://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/). It is pretty good.